# Best way to achieve late-stage polymorphism

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I have several disparate templated pure abstract classes. I derive from these to get a bunch of classes, and from there, I can use those to make a bunch of objects. I would like to put all of these objects into a container. However, they are all of different types. I am wondering how to accomplish this late-stage polymorphism.

Say this is my pre-existing code that I have right now:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class A{
public: 
    A() : m_num(1.0) {};
    virtual ~A() {};
    virtual void printNum() const = 0;
protected:
    T m_num;
};

template<typename T>
class B{
public: 
    B() : m_num(2.0) {};
    virtual ~B() {};
    virtual void printTwiceNum() const = 0;
protected:
    T m_num;
};

class A_example : public A<int>
{
public:
    A_example() : A<int>() {};
    void printNum() const { std::cout << m_num << "\n"; };
};


class B_example : public B<int>
{
public:
    B_example() : B<int>() {};
    void printTwiceNum() const { std::cout << 2*m_num << "\n"; };
};

int main(){
    A_example first;
    B_example second;
    first.printNum();
    second.printTwiceNum();

    return 0;
}
```

With more classes, it could get pretty messy inside of `main()`. Ideally I could jut iterate over the container and call `print()` on each element. My first thought is to use a `std::vector<unique_ptr<Base>>`. This seems to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> // new include
#include <memory> // new include
#include <utility> // new include

// new Base class here
class Base{
public: 
    virtual ~Base(){};
};

template<typename T>
class A : public Base{ // new inheritance here
public: 
    A() : m_num(1.0) {};
    virtual ~A() {};
    virtual void printNum() const = 0;
protected:
    T m_num;
};

template<typename T>
class B : public Base{ // new inheritance here as well
public: 
    B() : m_num(2.0) {};
    virtual ~B() {};
    virtual void printTwiceNum() const = 0;
protected:
    T m_num;
};

class A_example : public A<int>
{
public:
    A_example() : A<int>() {};
    void printNum() const { std::cout << m_num << "\n"; };
};


class B_example : public B<int>
{
public:
    B_example() : B<int>() {};
    void printTwiceNum() const { std::cout << 2*m_num << "\n"; };
};


int main(){

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> v;
    v.emplace_back( new A_example() );
    v.emplace_back( new B_example() );
    //v[0]->printNum(); // nope
    //v[1]->printTwiceNum(); // nope

    return 0;
}
```

This is cool because I didn't have to change `A_example` or `B_example`, and all I changed in `A` and  `B` was that I added `: public Base`. However, I have no idea how to call each elements `print***` function. Is there any way to call the `printNum()` and `printTwiceNum()` functions, and for them to be automatically recognized?

Comment: If all the interfaces are different then maybe polymorphism isn't the right tool for the job? Could you put them in separate containers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach is to just make a virtual function `Base::print` and have your derived classes implement it.  But that's not always appropriate.

Another approach is to branch on `dynamic_cast` conversions.  The premise there is that some functions are only available on some classes.  But this can get hairy especially when using class templates, as you must handle all expected template parameters.

To generalize this, you can use *interface classes*.  Let's say you have lots of different classes but only a small number of print variations.  In that case, it may make sense to do this:

```
class PrintNumInterface {
public:
    virtual void printNum() const = 0;
};

class PrintTwiceNumInterface {
public:
    virtual void printTwiceNum() const = 0;
};

template<typename T> class A : public Base, public PrintNumInterface { ... };
template<typename T> class B : public Base, public PrintTwiceNumInterface { ... };
```

And now, no matter how many additional classes or template expansions you have to deal with, you only need to handle these interfaces:

```
for (auto& p : v)
{
    if (PrintNumInterface* iface = dynamic_cast<PrintNumInterface*>(p.get())
        iface->printNum();
    else if (PrintTwiceNumInterface* iface = dynamic_cast<PrintTwiceNumInterface*>(p.get())
        iface->printTwiceNum();
}
```

Comment: Note that `A` and `B` are class templates, not classes.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I have made that change.